# Using JavaScript/ JQuery, can you make a link on click code fire

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using FireFox, Javascript and JQuery and I am a noob at all :-)
My understanding is that it is impossible to use any of the above to make the client browser execute an anchor click via code.
ie: the page I am working on has a button with an anchor tag to update the data being displayed (next 15 records).
Is this true? if not, can someone please assist with some guidance?

The LINK code that I am looking at is this one:

```
<li>
  <a href="#statistic=general;page=4;name=" target="self" class="ABC">
    <span class="btnBg">&nbsp;</span>
    <span class="icn next">&nbsp; </span>
  </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yup,

```
$(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
        //your function like window.location = this.href
    });
});
```

Comment: That sets the click handler. To execute the click via code (as the OP asks), just call `click()` with no arguments. For example: `$("a").click();`

Comment: Just to clarify, the link above is the existing code on the page that I want to execute with my function.  I wish to add a button on the page that will run my function (Collect the data) and then run the above link to get the next set of data.  I have the function to collect the data working.  Just can not get the function to call the link above.  This is what I have been told is impossible to do.